# (.Net 4.5) Problems Converting my WCF-Service to Rest-Service

Tags: c#, json, wcf, rest, .net-4.5

I have a working WCF-Service with one Method `GetCountries` . This function returns an array of `custom object DTOCountry`. Yet when i convert my method to rest, i can't seem to get it working. Moreover it keeps on pushing me towards my old `BasicHttpBinding` (in my WCF-Testclient).

Could someone point out what i'm doing wrong?

**My Config**

Endpoints (note the different contract that is linked):

```
    <service name="Partywhere.WCFService.Services.PublicServices" behaviorConfiguration="WCFService.PublicBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Partywhere.WCFService.Services.IPW_UserService" behaviorConfiguration="WCFServiceEndpoint.PublicBehavior">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="GeoRest" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="restfulBehavior" bindingConfiguration="MyWebHttp" contract="Partywhere.WCFService.Services.IPW_GeoService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" behaviorConfiguration="WCFServiceEndpoint.PublicBehavior"/>
  </service>
```

Behaviors:

```
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WCFServiceEndpoint.PublicBehavior" />
    <behavior name="restfulBehavior">
      <webHttp></webHttp>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WCFService.PublicBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

My bindings:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="Partywhere.WCFService.Services.PublicServices" maxBufferSize="500000000" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="500000000">
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <mexHttpBinding>
    <binding name="mex"/>
  </mexHttpBinding>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MyWebHttp" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" receiveTimeout="05:00:00" openTimeout="05:00:00" closeTimeout="05:00:00" sendTimeout="05:00:00">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

**My Interface**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPW_GeoService
{

    [OperationContract]
    DTOCountry[] GetAllCountries();
}
```

**My SVC**

```
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "GetAllCountries")]
    public DTOCountry[] GetAllCountries()
    {
        try
        {
            return _myCountryBl.GetAllCountries().ToArray();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

**Question:** Can someone spot the configuration error?
I address my method as follows `Http://localhost/PW_GeoService.svc/GeoRest/GetAllCountries`

**Note:**: Tried using WebInvoke() as WebGet()

**Note2:**: Tried decorating the interface aswell as the implementation of my service

**Update:** When addressing Client-Side i get the error : 400 Bad-Request.

Comment: what version of .net?  4.5?

Comment: yes that's right its 4.5. i'll add it to my question

Comment: What error it gives? Any exception is thrown?

Comment: No exception thrown/ no ouput given (Chrome). In firefox/IE i'm getting an 400-exception ´Invalid Request´

Comment: Can you browse your service in Browser?

Comment: Browsing: HttpBasicBinding yes but my WebhttpBinding not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. It was problem in my protocolmapping:

Original:

```
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>
```

Now (Working):

```
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
  <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
</protocolMapping>
```

Thanks for everyone for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try to look at this [documentation of WebGet attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.servicemodel.web.webgetattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). In the example this attribute decorates the interface. In your code you are decorating the implementation. I think this could be the source of your problem.

I made a simple WCF application and tried to reuse as much code and configuration as possible. I have created basic WCF application that is available in menu of visual studio. And it worked.

Here is my code:
Service contracts:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

namespace WcfService1
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "GetAllCountries")]
        DTOCountry[] GetAllCountries();
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService2
    {
        [OperationContract]
        DTOCountry[] GetAllCountries2();
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class DTOCountry
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Service implementation:

```
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace WcfService1
{
    [ServiceBehavior]
    public class Service1 : IService1, IService2
    {
        public DTOCountry[] GetAllCountries()
        {
            return new DTOCountry[2] { new DTOCountry { Name = "a" }, new DTOCountry { Name = "b" } };
        }

        public DTOCountry[] GetAllCountries2()
        {
            return new DTOCountry[2] { new DTOCountry { Name = "a" }, new DTOCountry { Name = "b" } };
        }
    }
}
```

And web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService1.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="WCFService.PublicBehavior">
        <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" address="basic" contract="WcfService1.IService2" behaviorConfiguration="WCFServiceEndpoint.PublicBehavior">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" address="rest" contract="WcfService1.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="restfulBehavior">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" behaviorConfiguration="WCFServiceEndpoint.PublicBehavior"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MyWebHttp" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" receiveTimeout="05:00:00" openTimeout="05:00:00" closeTimeout="05:00:00" sendTimeout="05:00:00">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="" maxBufferSize="500000000" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="500000000">
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WCFServiceEndpoint.PublicBehavior" />
        <behavior name="restfulBehavior">
          <webHttp></webHttp>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WCFService.PublicBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I made following request in IE11:

```
http://localhost:57925/Service1.svc/rest/GetAllCountries
```

and the response was

```
{"GetAllCountriesResult":[{"Name":"a"},{"Name":"b"}]}
```

Comment: Tried both decorating the interface and the implementation. Same issue. Tried WebInvoke() aswell. I was thinking more towards an configurationError

Comment: Thnx for the effort (+1). Will try to test it during my lunchbreak. Only difference i notice is the absence of an basichttp-endpoint in your config. Are there know problems between Basichttp & Rest that i'm not aware of?

Comment: None that I know of. I didn't use the binding because the endpoint behind it was using different contract. I tried to add another interface and updated my answer. It still works :)

Comment: Still not working. It really starts to piss me off .... (excuse me for my language) :'(

Comment: What exception are you receiving? Also try to enable includeExceptionDetailInFaults and browse to base url of your service to see if at least soap is working. When I've been extending my example and adding another interface I accidentally named the methods equally. It compiled but faulted in runtime when I accessed the base url of the service.

Comment: Soap is working. No problems there, its when i address the REST-Service. Then i get a '404' not found...

Comment: @svranken What is the base address of your service (the one you used to get to wsdl)? Also have you tried my example code if it is working on your PC?

Comment: Your examplecode works fine. its my code that appears to be broken. Http://localhost/PW_GeoService.svc?wsdl works brilliantly (gives me a basichttpbinfing) but when i try to address my REST: Http://localhost/PW_GeoService.svc/GeoRest/GetAllCountries that the thing goes haywire

Comment: OK, try to enable help page on webhttp binding endpoint using [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230442(v=vs.110).aspx). It will show (hopefully) what web methods are available.

Comment: Nope no results. It seems that address of my webhttp doesn't get registered... I'm getting an Http (400)-error on the Client Side (Bad Request)

Comment: I only got HTTP 400 if I browsed wrong URL. Are you really really sure that you type good url? Try to do the following: browse [http://localhost/](http://localhost/). Click `PW_GeoService.svc`. Add only `GeoRest/`. A documentation page should appear. Add `GetAllCountries`.

Comment: Nope still nothing. Its works right until the ´.svc´ A soon as i start to add GeoRest then the (400) error starts.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48528/discussion-between-pepo-and-svranken)